# Create API controller in sitecore

Tags: sitecore-api

I am using `Sitecore 10` and trying to implement an `API` controller, but I got this issue when calling API in postman  **https://{mydomain}/saveform**

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nSaveForm on type ATLP.Feature.SaveSitecoreForm.Controllers.SaveSitecoreFormController\r\nSaveForm on type ATLP.Feature.SaveSitecoreForm.Controllers.SaveSitecoreFormController",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"
}
```

this my controller

```
[ServicesController]
[RequiredApiKey]
public class SaveSitecoreFormController : ApiController
{
    private SaveFormRepository _repository;
    public SaveSitecoreFormController()
    {
        _repository = new SaveFormRepository();
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [Route("saveform")]
    public  IHttpActionResult SaveForm([FromBody]SitecoreFormDataModel formData)
    {
        List<FormFieldDataModel> FormFieldList = new List<FormFieldDataModel>();
        if (formData == null)
        {
            return BadRequest ("Missing form data");
        }
        else
        {
            var formId = formData.data.Where(f => f.key.Contains("FormItemId")).FirstOrDefault();
            Guid formGuid = new Guid(formId.value);
            var formEmailData = formData.data.Where(f => f.key.Contains("Email")).FirstOrDefault();
            if (formEmailData != null)
            {
                FormFieldDataModel emailFieldDataModel = new FormFieldDataModel
                {
                    FormFieldName = formEmailData.key,
                    FormFieldValue = formEmailData.value,
                    FormFieldGuid = new Guid("{B026F347-0CEE-4FF0-B435-E4737B253BDA}")
                };
                FormFieldList.Add(emailFieldDataModel);
                _repository.SaveFormData(formGuid, FormFieldList);
            }
            return Ok("Create CRM and Lead Objects Successful");
        }
    }
}
```

this serviceConfigurator class

```
public class ServicesConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
{
    public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(typeof(SaveSitecoreFormController),
            typeof(SaveSitecoreFormController)));
    }
}
```

and this config file

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <services>
        <configurator type="ATLP.Feature.SaveSitecoreForm.Services.ServicesConfigurator, ATLP.Feature.SaveSitecoreForm" />
    </services>
</sitecore>
```

any ideas what is missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an apiController you need to follow next steps

1 . Create a class which inherits from ApiController

```
public class PersonApiController : ApiController
```

2. You need to create your method which represent api call :

   ```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [Route("getvcard/{itemIdString}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetItemInformation(string itemIdString)
   ```
3. You need to register the ApiController

   ```
   public class Register : IServicesConfigurator
        {
            public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
            {

                serviceCollection.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(typeof(PersonApiController),
                    typeof(PersonApiController)));
            }
        }
   ```
4. You need to register in the configuration :

   ```
   <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
     <sitecore>
       <services>
         <configurator 
            type="yourNameSpace.ServicesConfigurator,yourNamespace" />
       </services>
      </sitecore>
    </configuration>
   ```
5. To call the api you need to call it in this way

   **https://yourhostname/getvarcad/itemid**